# TableLayoutPanel remove empty rows

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to remove all empty rows from a `TableLayoutPanel`. So far I have been able to do it this way

```
private void RemoveEmptyRows()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < tablePanel.RowCount - 1; row++)
    {
        bool hasControl = false;
        for (int col = 0; col < tablePanel.ColumnCount; col++)
        {
            if (tablePanel.GetControlFromPosition(col, row) != null)
            {
                hasControl = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!hasControl)
            tablePanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of this? My approach seems too overwhelmed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is a better way except that your code has some flaws. You can rely on `Linq` to make it little more concise but that may be inelegant as well as less readable and not debuggable at all since you shouldn't be using too much Linq to do this kind of a thing (personally I like it though!). Here is what you should do to your existing code:

```
private void RemoveEmptyRows()
{
    for (int row = tablePanel.RowCount -1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        bool hasControl = false;
        for (int col = 0; col < tablePanel.ColumnCount; col++)
        {
            if (tablePanel.GetControlFromPosition(col, row) != null)
            {
                hasControl = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasControl)
        {
            tablePanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row);
            tablePanel.RowCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

1. You should iterate from top to down since `RowCount` can change when evaluating it against `row` in your outer foreach loop.
2. You should also remove the row after removing the `RowStyle` simply by doing `RowCount--`.

Here is a `Linq` version:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, tablePanel.RowCount)
    .Except(tablePanel.Controls.OfType<Control>()
        .Select(c => tablePanel.GetRow(c)))
    .Reverse()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(rowIndex =>
     {
         tablePanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
         tablePanel.RowCount--;
     });
```

To break this down as to what it does (if you are not so familiar with Linq):

```
var listOfAllRowIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, tablePanel.RowCount);
var listOfControlsInTableLayoutPanel = tablePanel.Controls.OfType<Control>();
var listOfRowIndicesWithControl = listOfControlsInTableLayoutPanel.Select(c => tablePanel.GetRow(c));
var listOfRowIndicesWithoutControl = listOfAllRowIndices.Except(listOfRowIndicesWithControl);
var listOfRowIndicesWithoutControlSortedInDescendingOrder = listOfRowIndicesWithoutControl.Reverse(); //or .OrderByDescending(i => i);
```

And then:

```
listOfRowIndicesWithoutControlSortedInDescendingOrder.ToList().ForEach(rowIndex =>
{
    tablePanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
    tablePanel.RowCount--;
});
```

Another Linq version which may be more readable, but less efficient:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount)
    .Where(rowIndex => !tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
        .Select(c => tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(c))
        .Contains(rowIndex))
    .Reverse()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(rowIndex =>
    {
        tablePanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
        tablePanel.RowCount--;
    });
```

Comment: +1 for iterating bottom-to-top.... and Personally I hate LINQ, for no other reason that the syntax is so dense that I find it impregnable, and therefore my LINQ solutions tend to take longer to develop and be buggy to boot! Typically I find the non-linq version is quicker to write and easier maintain anyway... but maybe I just need more practive with LINQ, which I avoid by not preferring it. Sigh.

Comment: @corlettk Linq is cool, and I love it. The real benefit for me is that it frees me from writing repetitive-obvious code for simple tasks. But ya I do not like Linq for complex tasks. Multiple linq statements makes it hard to understand. For instance I like code like `myList.Where(this and that).Select(so and so).OrderBy(condition)` which is so simple ans readable, where as I hate code like `myList.GroupBy(condition).ToDictionary(selector, selector, hell lot of other selectors).Distinct().Zip(one another complex dictionary)`

Comment: Thanks for the bottom up approach. I was experiencing some weird behavior too. I'll try this.

Comment: I like it. Perhaps an extension method would work nicely here too.